# Rails 3.2.12 bootstrap-datepicker not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datepicker

I've been struggling to get the bootstrap-datepicker to work in my rails application.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!!

Rails -v: 3.2.12
jquery-rails: 3.0.4, 3.0.2, ....

Here is the js in my html file:

```
<link href="/assets/datepicker.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-transition.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-affix.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-alert.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-button.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-carousel.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-collapse.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-dropdown.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-modal.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-scrollspy.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-tab.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-tooltip.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-popover.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-typeahead.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-datepicker.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/application.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

html snippet:

```
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="vps_eta_date">Estimated arrival date</label>
    <div class="controls">    
        <div class="input-append date" id="dp3" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy">
             <input class="span2" size="16" id="vps_eta_date" name="vps[eta_date]" type="text" value="12-02-2013" readonly>
             <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-th"></i></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

html file also include the following script copied this from an example (http://vitalets.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/):

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        window.prettyPrint && prettyPrint();
        $('#dp1').datepicker({
            format: 'mm-dd-yyyy',
            todayBtn: 'linked'
        });

        $('#dp2').datepicker();
        $('#btn2').click(function(e){
            e.stopPropagation();
            $('#dp2').datepicker('update', '03/17/12');
        });             

        $('#dp3').datepicker();


        var startDate = new Date(2012,1,20);
        var endDate = new Date(2012,1,25);
        $('#dp4').datepicker()
            .on('changeDate', function(ev){
                if (ev.date.valueOf() > endDate.valueOf()){
                    $('#alert').show().find('strong').text('The start date can not be greater then the end date');
                } else {
                    $('#alert').hide();
                    startDate = new Date(ev.date);
                    $('#startDate').text($('#dp4').data('date'));
                }
                $('#dp4').datepicker('hide');
            });
        $('#dp5').datepicker()
            .on('changeDate', function(ev){
                if (ev.date.valueOf() < startDate.valueOf()){
                    $('#alert').show().find('strong').text('The end date can not be less then the start date');
                } else {
                    $('#alert').hide();
                    endDate = new Date(ev.date);
                    $('#endDate').text($('#dp5').data('date'));
                }
                $('#dp5').datepicker('hide');
            });

        //inline    
        $('#dp6').datepicker({
            todayBtn: 'linked'
        });

        $('#btn6').click(function(){
            $('#dp6').datepicker('update', '15-05-1984');
        });            

        $('#btn7').click(function(){
            $('#dp6').data('datepicker').date = null;
            $('#dp6').find('.active').removeClass('active');                
        });            
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [bootstrap-datepicker-rails gem](https://github.com/Nerian/bootstrap-datepicker-rails), I suggestion for using it.

Put `bootstrap-datepicker-rails` into your Gemfile;

```
gem 'bootstrap-datepicker-rails'
```

And run bundle, then Add this line to *app/assets/stylesheets/application.css*

```
 *= require bootstrap-datepicker
```

Add this line to *app/assets/javascripts/application.js*

```
 //= require bootstrap-datepicker
```

And on views (e.g form)

```
<%= f.text_field :mydate, 'data-behaviour' => 'datepicker' %>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $('[data-behaviour~=datepicker]').datepicker();
</script>
```

Or As component :

```
<div class="input-append date datepicker" data-date="12-02-2012" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy">
    <%= f.text_field :mydate, 'data-behaviour' => 'datepicker', :disabled => 'disable' %><span class="add-on"><i class="icon-th"></i></span>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $('.datepicker').datepicker();
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I followed the instructions but was not successful. It appears that the correct .js and .css files are included in the html file. the script snippet is also embedded in the html file, but the datepicker does NOT work. It has been 3 days and it is getting frustrating. I did get the datepicker to work in a very simple html file (non-rails) that included only the jquery.js and datepicker related js files.

Comment: Can you post `form`, `application.css`, `application.js` and head of `application.html` ?

Comment: application.css:/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or vendor/assets/stylesheets of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the top of the
 * compiled file, but it's generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *
 *= require_self
 *= require bootstrap-datepicker
 *= require_tree .
 */

Comment: @emmkaye you should post on your question,

Comment: application.js:
//
//
// WARNING: THE FIRST BLANK LINE MARKS THE END OF WHAT'S TO BE PROCESSED, ANY BLANK LINE SHOULD
// GO AFTER THE REQUIRES BELOW.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
// Loads all Bootstrap javascripts
//= require bootstrap
//= require bootstrap-datepicker
//= require_tree .

Comment: form:<script type="text/javascript">
  $('.datepicker').datepicker();
</script>
<div class="input-append date datepicker" data-date="12-02-2012" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy">
    <%= f.text_field "estimated_arrival_date", 'data-behaviour' => 'datepicker', :disabled => 'disable' %><span class="add-on"><i class="icon-th"></i></span>
</div>

Comment: From all the reading on the web, could this really be an issue with the numerous javascript files I have included?

Comment: @anon... what does "post on your question" mean? Does it mean I need to use the "Answer your question" button?

Comment: @emmkaye you should edit your question and put them to your question

Answer (score 0):

I have directly included the following in my  section:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

I used the before mentioned form and javascript snippent.
jquery-ui's datpicker is working for me now and I will continue with this solution and revisit this later.

Thanks for you help, but there is something screwy with the both the bootstrap-datepicker-rails and jquery-ui-rails gems and how they interact with all the other javascript files.

Comment: I never had a problem with jquery-ui-rails, but bootstrap-datepicker-rails is either severely broken, or just so poorly documented and convoluted, that many cannot get it to work even after days of trying.